# Can't figure out what's wrong in my Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can't figure out why my Javascript code won't run to show a letter grade and change the background color. I'm new at this, but thought I had it right...any ideas?

1. Writes the numeric grade in the bottom left cell of the table.
2. And the associated letter grade in the bottom right cell of the table. 
   (For this problem use: A >= 90 > B >= 80 > C >= 70 > D >= 60 > F)
3. If the grade is passing the background color of the letter grade cell changes to green. If the grade is failing the background color of the letter grade cell should turn red.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Lab11aKL.html</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style>

  </style>
  <script>
    function addNumbers() {
      var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
      var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
      var t3 = document.getElementById("t3");
      var t4 = document.getElementById("t4");
      var t5 = document.getElementById("t5");
      var t6 = document.getElementById("t6");

      answer.value = parseFloat(t1.value * .20) + parseFloat(t2.value * .20) +
        parseFloat(t3.value * .30) + parseFloat(t4.value * .125) +
        parseFloat(t5.value * .125) + parseFloat(t6.value * .05);
    }

    function gradeLetter() {
      var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
      var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
      var t3 = document.getElementById("t3");
      var t4 = document.getElementById("t4");
      var t5 = document.getElementById("t5");
      var t6 = document.getElementById("t6");

      var ct1 = parseFloat(t1.value * .20);
      var ct2 = parseFloat(t2.value * .20);
      var ct3 = parseFloat(t3.value * .30)
      var ct4 = parseFloat(t4.value * .125);
      var ct5 = parseFloat(t4.value * .125);
      var ct6 = parseFloat(t6.value * .05);

      if (answer >= 90 > ) {
        answergrade = 'A';
        document.getElementById("answergrade").style.backgroundColor =
          'green';
      } else if (answer >= 80 > ) {
        answergrade = 'B';
        document.getElementById("answergrade").style.backgroundColor =
          'green';
      } else if (answer >= 70 > ) {
        answergrade = 'C';
        document.getElementById("answergrade").style.backgroundColor =
          'green';
      } else if (answer >= 60 > ) {
        answergrade = 'D';
        document.getElementById("answergrade").style.backgroundColor =
          'green';
      } else(answer < 60) {
        answergrade = 'F';
        document.getElementById("answergrade").style.backgroundColor =
          'red';
      }
    }
  </script>


</head>

<body>

  <form name="tform" id="tform">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Score</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test 2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t2" id="t2" /></td>
      </tr>
      <td>Final Exam</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="t3" id="t3" /></td>
      </tr>
      <td>Labs</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="t4" id="t4" /></td>
      </tr>
      <td>Project</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="t5" id="t5" /></td>
      </tr>
      <td>Quizzes</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="t6" id="t6" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <th colspan="2">
          <input type="button" name="b1" id="b1" value="Calculate Grade" onclick="addNumbers(); gradeLetter()" />
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="answergrade" id="answergrade" /></td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a variable for answer anywhere.

Comment: What isn't working about it? What is happening and how does it differ from the results you're trying to achieve? Additionally, your title should be a brief summary of the issue - currently your title could apply to *any JavaScript question ever*.

Comment: Learn how to ask a question: 1. What does it do, or not do, that you expect it to do? 2. Did you check your browser's console for errors? If so, are there any? 3. Set up a jsFiddle or a code snippet that we can run, so we don't have to recreate the situation exactly ourseleves.

Comment: There are syntax errors in your javascript.  Learn how to use your Browser's Developer console to troubleshoot them.

Comment: Use an array to store the values, and some iteration method to read them, that what you have is ... awful ...

Comment: @Teemu it's obvious this is a "first week in javascript" kind of thing, so I would avoid what would be, at this point, an unnecessary complication

Comment: @Our_Benefactors Then there's something wrong with the teaching methods ...

Comment: @Teemu we're getting off topic, but I don't think it's unreasonable to assign this kind of an exercise before teaching about arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is missing values. Take a look at if/else clauses

```
else if (answer >=70 >{??})
```

There is no x>a>y type of comparison in javascript.

Comment: but..but..but.. there should be. would require less code :)

Comment: In the future, please consider withholding answers to off-topic questions. Per meta: [*"If the question is (...)  off topic on all SE sites: Don't answer the question"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions). Additionally, you run the risk of receiving downvotes, as etiquette dictates that [answers on off-topic questions get downvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions). It encourages bad question-asking habits.

Comment: @Santi I am not sure if I am following. Why it is an off-topic question?

Comment: ["What's on topic?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions asking for homework help must include a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."* **|** *"Questions asking for debugging help must include a specific problem or error ...and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it"* **|** *"Questions about a problem that was caused by a simple typographical error are off-topic"*... etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here.

1. You don't have a variable defined for `answer` that you're referring to in the `addNumbers()` function.
2. You are setting `answer.value` in `addNumbers()`, but then comparing to `answer` in all of your conditionals in the `gradeLetter()` function.
3. t1 through t6 don't have a value in HTML.
4. `answergrade` being calculated in `gradeLetter()` isn't being written to that HTML element
5. Your conditionals aren't defined correctly
6. You can't have `else (condition){//condition is true execute this stuff}` , it's just `else{//execute this code automatically}`. When there's a condition after the first `if` statement use `else if (condition){//condition is true execute this stuff}`

Please see the below code which should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Lab11aKL.html</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
</style>
<script>
var answer;

function addNumbers()
{
    var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
    var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
    var t3 = document.getElementById("t3");
    var t4 = document.getElementById("t4");
    var t5 = document.getElementById("t5");
    var t6 = document.getElementById("t6");

    answer = parseFloat(t1.value * .20) + parseFloat(t2.value * .20) + 
    parseFloat(t3.value * .30) + parseFloat(t4.value * .125) + 
    parseFloat(t5.value * .125) + parseFloat(t6.value * .05);
}

function gradeLetter()
{
var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
var t3 = document.getElementById("t3");
var t4 = document.getElementById("t4");
var t5 = document.getElementById("t5");
var t6 = document.getElementById("t6");

var ct1 = parseFloat(t1.value * .20);
var ct2 = parseFloat(t2.value * .20);
var ct3 = parseFloat(t3.value * .30) 
var ct4 = parseFloat(t4.value * .125);
var ct5 = parseFloat(t4.value * .125);
var ct6 = parseFloat(t6.value * .05);

        if (answer >=90)
            {
            answergrade = 'A';
            document.getElementById ("answergrade").style.backgroundColor = 
'green';
            }
        else if (answer >=80)
            {
            answergrade = 'B';
            document.getElementById ("answergrade").style.backgroundColor = 
'green';
            }
        else if (answer >=70)
            {
            answergrade = 'C';
            document.getElementById ("answergrade").style.backgroundColor = 
'green';
            }
        else if (answer >=60)
            {
            answergrade = 'D';
            document.getElementById ("answergrade").style.backgroundColor = 
'green';
            }
        else if (answer <60)
            {
            answergrade = 'F';
            document.getElementById ("answergrade").style.backgroundColor =         
'red';
            }
var answerElem = document.getElementById('answergrade')
answerElem.innerText = answergrade;
}
</script>


</head>
<body>

<form name="tform" id="tform">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t1" id="t1"/>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t2" id="t2"/>50</td>
    </tr>
        <td>Final Exam</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t3" id="t3"/>100</td>
    </tr>
        <td>Labs</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t4" id="t4"/>90</td>
    </tr>
        <td>Project</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t5" id="t5"/>70</td>
    </tr>
        <td>Quizzes</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t6" id="t6"/>85</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <th colspan="2">
        <input type="button" name="b1" id="b1"
        value="Calculate Grade"
        onclick="addNumbers(); gradeLetter()"/>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="answer" id="answer"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="answergrade" id="answergrade"/></td>
    </tr>

</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems.  Some of them are clearly visible if you use a browser's developer console to troubleshoot.  If you are going to program javascript, it's a must to learn how to use the console.

Below is a working snippet.  Run it to see it work.

I commented in the code below the variety of problems (just before the fixed code).

```js
function addNumbers() {
  var t1 = document.getElementById( "t1" );
  var t2 = document.getElementById( "t2" );
  var t3 = document.getElementById( "t3" );
  var t4 = document.getElementById( "t4" );
  var t5 = document.getElementById( "t5" );
  var t6 = document.getElementById( "t6" );
  var answer = document.getElementById('answer');

  answer.value = parseFloat( t1.value * .20 ) + parseFloat( t2.value * .20 ) +
    parseFloat( t3.value * .30 ) + parseFloat( t4.value * .125 ) +
    parseFloat( t5.value * .125 ) + parseFloat( t6.value * .05 );
}

function gradeLetter() {
  // you weren't getting the value for "answer"
  // the + casts this to a number, so the comparisons work properly
  var answer = +document.getElementById('answer').value;
  
  var t1 = document.getElementById( "t1" );
  var t2 = document.getElementById( "t2" );
  var t3 = document.getElementById( "t3" );
  var t4 = document.getElementById( "t4" );
  var t5 = document.getElementById( "t5" );
  var t6 = document.getElementById( "t6" );

  var ct1 = parseFloat( t1.value * .20 );
  var ct2 = parseFloat( t2.value * .20 );
  var ct3 = parseFloat( t3.value * .30 )
  var ct4 = parseFloat( t4.value * .125 );
  var ct5 = parseFloat( t4.value * .125 );
  var ct6 = parseFloat( t6.value * .05 );

  // This is incorrect and causes a syntax error
  // if ( answer >= 90 > ) {
  if ( answer >= 90 ) {
    answergrade                                                    = 'A';
    document.getElementById( "answergrade" ).style.backgroundColor =
      'green';
  }
  else if ( answer >= 80 ) {
    answergrade                                                    = 'B';
    document.getElementById( "answergrade" ).style.backgroundColor =
      'green';
  }
  else if ( answer >= 70 ) {
    answergrade                                                    = 'C';
    document.getElementById( "answergrade" ).style.backgroundColor =
      'green';
  }
  else if ( answer >= 60 ) {
    answergrade                                                    = 'D';
    document.getElementById( "answergrade" ).style.backgroundColor =
      'green';
  }
  else if (answer < 60)
  {
    answergrade                                                    = 'F';
    document.getElementById( "answergrade" ).style.backgroundColor =
      'red';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Lab11aKL.html</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
</style>


</head>
<body>

<form name="tform" id="tform">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t1" id="t1"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t2" id="t2"/></td>
    </tr>
        <td>Final Exam</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t3" id="t3"/></td>
    </tr>
        <td>Labs</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t4" id="t4"/></td>
    </tr>
        <td>Project</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t5" id="t5"/></td>
    </tr>
        <td>Quizzes</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t6" id="t6"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <th colspan="2">
        <input type="button" name="b1" id="b1"
        value="Calculate Grade"
        onclick="addNumbers(); gradeLetter()"/>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="answer" id="answer"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="answergrade" id="answergrade"/></td>
    </tr>

</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Close out you if and if else conditions:

```
if (answer >=90 >){
        answergrade = 'A';
        document.getElementById ("answergrade").style.backgroundColor = 
        'green';
}
```

Should be

```
 if (answer >=90){
         answergrade = 'A';
         document.getElementById ("answergrade").style.backgroundColor = ` 
         'green';
 }
```

And the if else conditions need to be closed as well

```
if (answer >=80){
        answergrade = 'B';
        document.getElementById ("answergrade").style.backgroundColor = 
        'green';
 }
```

Should be

```
if (answer >=80 && answer < 90){
       answergrade = 'B';
       document.getElementById ("answergrade").style.backgroundColor = 
       'green';
 }
```

Comment: These are called conditionals, not loops

Comment: `if (answer >=90 >)...`, `if (answer >=80 >)...`?

Comment: @Kentuckiansmilo with concepts as basic as this, yes

Comment: @Kentuckiansmilo also the overall logical structure is correct. There's no need to test answer >= 80 && answer < 90, that's already handled by if(){} else if(){} ...

Comment: @Santi you are only stating in those instances answer Greater than or equal to 90 and then just a Greater than with out variable of declaration of statement. This value "&&" means "And". This value "||" means "Or" this value but with any operator you have you must have a value to compare to.

Comment: @Kentuckiansmilo I'm aware. I was pointing out the `>` at the end of your `if` conditions. It's syntactically incorrect.